# Vertical and horizantal Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to build Scrollview that scrolls horizontally and vertically 
i tried the below code but its not working

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView01" 
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   /// whatever goes here
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771479/4196092) and tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716638/4196092) too, is there any open source to this kind of View? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- put your subviews here -->

</HorizontalScrollView>
```