# Cannot scroll in android emulator

Tags: java, android, scroll

Is it possible to scroll using android emulator when the orientation is in landscape? If yes, then I must be missing out something..please help me...Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="|"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1">

                   .....
  </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: yes , it is absolutely possible to scroll in both directions on emulators and devices

Comment: **Yes** the scroll should work in emulator, and your code looks OK.  In some devices (old) `Scrollview` is not allowed as parent layout, so  try to add a `LinearLayout` as parent for your xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** the scroll should work in emulator, and your code looks OK.

In some (old) devices/emulators `Scrollview` is not allowed as parent layout, so try to add a `LinearLayout` as parent for your xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TableLayout
             ....
          </TableLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it scroll verticle?

Comment: ScrollView always scroll vertically.

Comment: If I want to scroll horizontal, does it sounds possible?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) instead of ScrollView. If you want a Vertical **and** Horizontal scroll see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771455/android-how-to-allow-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling)

Comment: Thanks...will give u feedback tomorrow after I try

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. You can add:  `android:fillViewport="true"`.

If *that* does not work, then wrap **`LinearLayout` (as a parent) around Scrollview**. I hope that works for you.

Please check this for more information:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: How to scroll vertical?

Comment: @Hoo Let me inform the above logic works or not ? If not the Create Linear Layout as parent then set Scrollview

Comment: @Hoo Glad to hear That .

Comment: But how to scroll vertical instead of horizontal?