# vertical recyclerView and Horizontal recyclerview scrolling together

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, scrollview

in my Project I want to have two `Recyclerview` (first one Horizontal and second Vertical)
if I scroll screen (vertically) I want both of them scroll together.

[image: recyclerview scroll]

i tryed some way but not worked please help me

my xml of fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.Tabs.FarsiF.FarsiBadr">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id_Horizental_badr_farsi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id_vertical_badr_farsi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

my class of fragment

```
public class FarsiBadr extends Fragment {
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter;
    List<Items> lstItems;
    public FarsiBadr() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_farsi_badr, container, false);
        lstItems = new ArrayList<>();
        lstItems.add(new Items("1 Tv", "11111", "77777", "horizental", R.drawable.gemtv));
        lstItems.add(new Items("2 Tv", "22222", "88888", "horizental", R.drawable.bbc));
        lstItems.add(new Items("3 Tv", "33333", "99999", "horizental", R.drawable.voa));
        lstItems.add(new Items("4 Tv", "44444", "44444", "horizental", R.drawable.manoto));
        //horizontal recycler view
        RecyclerView myrv = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id_Horizental_badr_farsi);
        myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstItems);
        myrv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        //vertical mode
        RecyclerView verticalmode = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id_vertical_badr_farsi);
        myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstItems);
        verticalmode.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
        verticalmode.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just by changing `scrollview` to `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` 
you can solve your problem

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".multi.TabFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchintabbadrkurdi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id_badr_kurdish_hor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id_badr_kurdish"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```